# Can't run any scripts in pywikibot

Tags: python, wikipedia, pywikibot

I am trying to use pywikibot, but I can't any script of the scripts. They all return the same error message:

```
python3 .\pwb.py .\scripts\listpages.py
ERROR: Unable to execute script because no generator was defined.
Use -help for further information.
```

I am not experienced in python or pywikibot, so I am not sure what's going on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, page generators are predifined switches you have to use:

```
python3 .\pwb.py .\scripts\listpages.py -search:'hello' -limit:10
```

In the above example `-search` is a page generator and `-limit` is a filter.

More information can be found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Page_Generators).

Answer (score 0):

Using `-help` option is a good way to find all generators which can be used with that script.